# F# remove function handler

Tags: .net, events, f#

So, I have a function that I want to execute on an event trigger, but I want to remove it later. What do I do for this? I know that F# events have the `Add` method that adds a function as a handler, but you can't remove this function. I understand, but I can't find how to create any delegate at all! (Well, there *is* the `type Foo = delegate of type1 -> type2`, but I don't understand its usage...)

EDIT: Here's a more clear example of what I want to do, in code:

```
// Define and publish event
let _someEvent = new Event<string>()
let SomeEvent = someEvent.Publish

// Normally, I'd do this to use it:
SomeEvent.Add (fun arg -> printfn "Argument: %s" arg)

// Trigger the event
someEvent.Trigger "Hello world"
```

But my problem is that I want to remove this hook sometime. I know that its possible with delegates... just don't know precisely how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another option is to use the Subscribe method and unsubscribe using Dispose:

```
// Define and publish event
let someEvent = new Event<string>()
let SomeEvent = someEvent.Publish

// Subscribe to event
let subscription =
    SomeEvent.Subscribe (fun arg -> printfn "Argument: %s" arg)

// Trigger the event
someEvent.Trigger "Hello world"

// Unsubscribe
subscription.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 6):

Yep, just use a Handler.

```
// Define and publish event
let _someEvent = new Event<string>()
let SomeEvent = _someEvent.Publish

// wrap function in handler
let handler = Handler<string>(fun _ arg -> printfn "Argument: %s" arg)

// add
SomeEvent.AddHandler handler

// remove
SomeEvent.RemoveHandler handler
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a delegate in F# like you create any other object.  Simply pass a function to its constructor.  You can also remove handlers from events the same way you do in any .Net language, using `RemoveHandler`.  You need to be sure you pass it the same delegate that was added in the first place.

This example (which you can run in FSI) creates a `PaintEventHandler` that fills the form blue, and adds it to the form's `Paint` event.  The button on the form is then set to remove the paint handler from the event, and force the form to redraw.

```
open System
open System.Drawing
open System.Windows.Forms

let form = new Form()

let paintHandler =
    PaintEventHandler( // The function is passed to the delegate constructor.
        fun sender e ->
            e.Graphics.Clear Color.CornflowerBlue
    )

form.Paint.AddHandler paintHandler // Handler added.

let btn = new Button()
btn.Text <- "Remove Handler"
btn.Width <- 200;
btn.Click.Add (fun e ->
    form.Paint.RemoveHandler paintHandler // Handler removed.
    form.Invalidate() // Redraw
)
form.Controls.Add btn

form.Show()
```

It's important to note that `AddHandler`/`RemoveHandler` take a normal delegate, but `Add` takes a function of a different signiture. (The `sender` parameter is missing.)