# F# propper remove of ElapsedEventHandler handler

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Hi I have a question I have quick program that will do something in every 10 seconds and it looks simple:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    let timer = new Timer(float 10000)
    let OnTimedEvent (frameId:uint32) : ElapsedEventHandler = new ElapsedEventHandler (fun obj args -> printfn "DATE: %A FRAME: %i" DateTime.Now frameId)

    while(true) do
        let keyStroke = Console.ReadKey() 
        if keyStroke.Key.Equals(ConsoleKey.Enter) then
            let frameId = 1u
            timer.AutoReset <- true
            timer.Elapsed.RemoveHandler(OnTimedEvent frameId)
            timer.Elapsed.AddHandler(OnTimedEvent frameId)
            timer.Start();
        else
            printfn "%c pressed" keyStroke.KeyChar
    0
```

Problem is I can not properly remove handler as it is, If i press enter once it starts and gives me one message every 10 sec so thi is what I am aiming for. But if i press enter 3 times it increments and gives me 3 messeges and so on, but i only want one.

Another thing is that if I remove parameter from it it works perfectly, so i suppose problem is with parameter. Any solutions for this?

Comment: You will need to keep a reference to each handler that you add, so that you can remove it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14535002/167920

Comment: Possible duplicate of [F# remove function handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533489/f-remove-function-handler)

Comment: I tried the that answer and it is problematic, can you support code example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your current implementation is that every call to `OnTimedEvent` returns a new instance of the `ElapsedEventHandler`. When you call it as follows:

```
timer.Elapsed.RemoveHandler(OnTimedEvent frameId)
```

you are removing a new handler that has not previously been registerd and so nothing actually happens. When you change your code to add/remove the same handler, then you are always using the same instance:

```
let frameId = 1u
let timedHandler = new ElapsedEventHandler (fun obj args -> 
    printfn "DATE: %A FRAME: %i" DateTime.Now frameId)

timer.Elapsed.RemoveHandler(timedHandler)
timer.Elapsed.AddHandler(timedHandler)
```

Now you do not have a good way of passing the `frameId` to your event handler. In your code, `frameId` is always `1u` and so it's hard to see what you actually want, but you could make it mutable:

```
let mutable frameId = 1u
let timedHandler = new ElapsedEventHandler (fun obj args -> 
    printfn "DATE: %A FRAME: %i" DateTime.Now frameId)

frameId <- 2u
timer.Elapsed.RemoveHandler(timedHandler)
timer.Elapsed.AddHandler(timedHandler)
```

That said, it's not really clear what you are trying to do and perhaps there is an altogether different way of doing what you want.

A completely different approach would be to use `MailboxProcessor` that keeps the current `frameId` and handles two types of messages - one triggered every 10 seconds by a timer and one that can be used to change the frame ID:

```
type Message = 
  | Tick 
  | ChangeFrameId of uint32 

let agent = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox -> 
  let rec run frameId = async {
    let! msg = inbox.Receive()
    match msg with
    | ChangeFrameId newId -> 
        return! run newId
    | Tick ->
        printfn "DATE: %A FRAME: %i" DateTime.Now frameId
        return! run frameId }
  run 1u)

let timer = new Timer(float 10000, AutoReset = true)
timer.Elapsed.Add(fun _ -> agent.Post(Tick))
timer.Start()

agent.Post(ChangeFrameId 2u)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code refactors what you have to store the handler so that it can be removed.

```
open System
open System.Timers

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let timer = new Timer(float 10000, AutoReset = true)
    let onTimedEvent (frameId: uint32) : ElapsedEventHandler = new ElapsedEventHandler (fun obj args -> printfn "DATE: %A FRAME: %i" DateTime.Now frameId)
    let rec readKey frameId =
        let handler = onTimedEvent frameId
        timer.Elapsed.AddHandler(handler)
        timer.Start()
        let keyStroke = Console.ReadKey() 
        timer.Stop()
        timer.Elapsed.RemoveHandler(handler)
        printfn "%c pressed" keyStroke.KeyChar
        let nextFrameId = 
            if keyStroke.Key.Equals(ConsoleKey.Enter) then
                frameId + 1u
            else
                frameId
        readKey(nextFrameId)
    readKey(1u)
    0
```

There may be better ways to accomplish what you are after, but this answers your question.